# Deploy 3rd party JAR to local repository

Tags: java, maven

I have a jar that I would like to deploy using `deploy:deploy-file` to a local directory. What should I use for the required -DrepositoryId and -Durl options?

my current attempt:

```
egeller$ mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=net.sample \
-DartifactId=sample-artifact -Dversion=4.5.1  -Dpackaging=jar \
-Dfile=sample-sdk.jar -DrepositoryId=local \
-Durl=file://Users/egeller/agent/deploy-agent/
```

results in the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: 
Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact net.sample:sample-artifact:jar:4.5.1 from/to local (file://Users/egeller/agent/deploy-agent/): 
Repository path /egeller/agent/deploy-agent/ does not exist, and cannot be created.
```

thanks!

Comment: does _/Users/egeller/agent/deploy-agent_ exist ?

Comment: Ah! So I was writing an absolute directory rather than a relative one. setting `-Durl` to `file://m2-repo` created an `m2-repo` directory which it deployed to.

Comment: no more issues right >

Comment: No more issues! Case closed.

Comment: closing it by answering for others reference :)

Answer (score 1):

> Repository path /egeller/agent/deploy-agent/ does not exist, and cannot be created.

means you provided incorrect path as per the comment discussion

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I should have set `-Durl` to a directory relative to the current working directory, rather than an absolute path. `-DrepositoryId` can be left blank in this case.

Working version:

```
egeller$ mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=net.sample \
-DartifactId=sample-artifact -Dversion=4.5.1  -Dpackaging=jar \
-Dfile=sample-sdk.jar \
-Durl=file://repo-name
```